# How pass all values outside the loop to call_user_func_array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am passing the $instance to call_user_func_array and SendBatchSms function, however the $response is only using the last $token in the loop, extending the loop works well but it is slow, how can I pass the $instance to call_user_func_array function with all loop values and not the last one. I am new to php

```
foreach($result as $row){
    $token = $row['token'];
    $version = "v1"; //DONT change unless you are using a different version
    $instance = new BongaTech($token, $version);
    $list[] = new Sms($sender, $phone, $message, $correlator, null, $endpoint);
}


//   $list = null;
  if($list !== null){ 

  $row_chunks = array_chunk($list, 100);
  ////////here we have 100 messages on each chunk
    ///////Loop through the messages in side the chunk
    foreach ($row_chunks as $sms){
    
        $response = call_user_func_array(array($instance, "sendBatchSMS"), $sms);
        
        $response = json_encode($response, true);
        $results = json_decode($response, true);
        print_r($response);
}
```

Comment: shouldnt  `$response = call_user_func_array...` be in the loop? else $instance is going to be the last one, whats the use of $list shouldn't it be $sms?

Comment: and why are you encoding only to decode on the next line

Comment: If I put the $response in the loop it loops the function and not the $list thus takes more time, the SendBatchsms should sent 100 calls per request

Comment: Please check, I have done some edits

Answer (score 1):

AS you see instance is changing for each loop. hence you will have multiple responses.
Try making an array of response as shown in below:
NOTE: I am assuming that $list[] is a set of SMS in this solution.

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
$token = $row['token'];
$version = "v1"; //DONT change unless you are using a different version
$instance = new BongaTech($token, $version);
$sms = new Sms($sender, $phone, $message, $correlator, null, $endpoint);
$response[] = call_user_func_array(array($instance, "sendBatchSMS"), $sms);
}
$response = json_encode($response, true);
print_r($response);
```